# GitHub Pages for Private Repository

Tags: github, github-pages

Anyone know if there's a way to create GitHub Pages for a Private Repo?

I was just thinking about the possibility to use GitHub Pages to host a small website, but keep the source repository private. This way the only way the content would be exposed would be through the public GitHub Pages URL.

FYI, I would just try it and see, but I don't want to convert to a paid GitHub account at this point until I know if this is possible.

Comment: Does anyone know what happens to the site if you convert a public repo (with published pages) to a now free private repo?

Comment: @Rico if you are not a pro user, site will stop working. "GitHub Pages is available in public repositories with GitHub Free, and in public and private repositories with GitHub Pro ..." source : https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-github-pages/

Comment: It will stop working. To make it work either you need to make your repo public or buy github pro.

Comment: This is possible for free with Gitlab Pages.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

**As of August 2020**

It is only possible with GitHub Pro, GitHub Team, GitHub Enterprise Cloud, and GitHub Enterprise Server.

[image]

See: [What is GitHub pages](https://help.github.com/en/articles/what-is-github-pages)

Comment: I contacted GitHub support and they replied back confirming this. They stated "You can host a GitHub Pages site from a private repository, however all published sites are public."

Comment: It's only possible though when you have the Pro account. Maybe you could update your answer.

Comment: This should probably be updated - there is no Github Pro now, right?

Comment: @SteveBennett When I go to https://github.com/account/upgrade, it is still listed as "GitHub Pro" at $4/month. Seems to be the same thing as "GitHub Team" as described on https://github.com/pricing, since it's the same price. In any case, this answer is still correct. You need to pay. I just tried it and posted an image of the problem

Comment: To add to this, you can now set GitHub Pages Visibility to 'Private' which means that only people with access to this repository can see this page.

Comment: You need the Enterprise plan to publish private Pages. So your Pages will be public even if you're on Team. Nice going Github!

Comment: I swear several months ago you could have private pages, and now their documentation says it's only for enterprise cloud. I imagine this could change ago too though  https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/changing-the-visibility-of-your-github-pages-site