# How do I hide my github profile subdomain repository?

Tags: github, github-pages

Every github profile/organization has it's custom subdomain which is `username.github.io`. In order to customize and publish it to github pages we needs to make it's repository which is named exactly the same `username.github.io`'s visibility to public. But I've seen that people are hiding this repository, even from the repository tab but still publishing the page. How to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub Pages for Private Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744980/github-pages-for-private-repository)

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible with GitHub Pro, GitHub Team, GitHub Enterprise Cloud, and GitHub Enterprise Server.

Comment: Okay. But assuming the OP has one of those subscriptions, how do they do it?