# My commit log shows '[ci skip]' and my github page is not updated after changes?

Tags: git, gitlab, github-actions, gitlab-ci

My GitHub page just can't update after changes. Even though the .html source files in my repo have been changed, my website shows no updates.

In the `master` branch where I write the text, I made a change and committed it with a simple comment "trival" *(sorry for the typo)* and pushed it. Usually, GitHub will automatically build .html files in the `gh-pages` branch and show them on my website, where I can check the deployment process in the `action` menu. But today my website does not show changes, and when I check the commit logs, I see a weird "**[ci skip]**" note in the `gh-pages` branch. I think this has something to do with my website problem.
[image]

My `master` branch commit log is normal. [image]

And the deployment process in the `action` menu shows success.[image]

Can anybody help me with this problem? Thanks!

---

Additional information: A few days ago I used `git rebase` commend to merge some of my commits. I don't know if it caused somethings.

Comment: `[ci skip]` is in the commit messsge. Someone wrote that

Comment: @evolutionxbox But I did not write [ci skip] when committing. I only wrote "trival" and pushed it in the `master` branch. GitHub deploys the `gh-pages` automatically.

Comment: Can you check for a `.github/workflows` directory? Are there any `.yaml` files in it?

Comment: @dan1st thanks for your advice but I figured out what was causing the problem - my GitHub Pro subscription had expired so the page for my private repo didn't deploy. Pretty dumb...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this commit from github come, but the [ci skip] is used to skip the workflow who deploy your website.

> Link for the [ci skip] : https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/skipping-workflow-runs

Maybe try to run the workflow manually .

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally figured out what was causing the problem - turns out my **GitHub Pro subscription had expired**. Pretty dumb, I know! Anyway, that's why my source files had changed but my page wasn't deploying.

The repo for my website is private, so according to current GitHub policy (you can learn from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28744980/10606134)), having a page for a private repo is only possible with GitHub Pro.